# Assetic: Cannot find module 'less'

Tags: less, laravel-4, npm, assetic

The problem:

- I am using laravel 4 + basset for asset management (OSX).
- i have added the twitter bootstrap to my composer as a dependency.
- I want to compile the less files into a collection:

  ```
  Basset::collection('TwitterBootstrap', function($collection)
  {
      // Collection definition.
      $collection->add('../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less');
  })->apply('Less');
  ```
- I then try to build the collection:

  ```
  php artisan basset:build TwitterBootstrap
  ```
- Which throws the error:

  ```
  [Assetic\Exception\FilterException]
    An error occurred while running:
    '/usr/local/bin/node' '/private/var/folders/f4/xjby77695pbcgfdjfclfdqd40000gn/T/assetic_less5y7dnh'

    Error Output:

    module.js:340
        throw err;
              ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'less'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/f4/xjby77695pbcgfdjfclfdqd40000gn/T/assetic_less5y7dnh:1:74)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
  ```

I have installed less globally - im unsure why this is throwing errors/what to fix (my path? a node config? an assetic config?)

Comment: I'm not sure about laravel, but I have had this problem with symfony and it was due to having the wrong path in my parameters config. Once I got the path to the node modules corrected, assetic worked just fine.

Comment: Same problem, this config path fix worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218206/symfony2-3-configure-assetic-with-less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by installing less with npm :

```
npm install less
```

To use less globally, do not run "npm install less" at the root of your project.
Instead add a symlink to the global one (/home/{user}/node_modules/less/) in your project :

```
ln -s /home/{user}/node_modules/less/ /path/to/project/node_modules/less
ln -s /home/{user}/node_modules/less/bin/lessc /path/to/project/node_modules/less/.bin/lessc
```

Comment: Please see my comment below - I do not want to install less on a per project basis. I want less globally.

Comment: I appreciate the response, and I have accepted this as an answer - but its not ideal. While it may work, it doesn't help me understand the error, or why it was occuring.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install less?

```
npm install less
```

Reference: https://npmjs.org/package/less

Edit... Just saw your footnote.

Another option would be to install lessPHP via composer and use `LessphpFilter` instead of `LessFilter`

Comment: While i *could* install less on a project level, that seems like an easy out and still doesn't address the issue. Also the lessPHP is only at 98% or so of the less npm module (according to comments online) and seems like a bandaid over a bigger problem.