# symfony2.3 configure assetic with less

Tags: node.js, configuration, less, symfony-2.3, assetic

I am using Symfony "2.3.*" and I attempt to make assetic less filter working.
I do all of this in the "dev" environment.

When I issue the `config:dump-reference assetic` I get the following output:

```yaml
assetic:
    debug:                %kernel.debug%
    use_controller:
        enabled:              %kernel.debug%
        profiler:             false
    read_from:            %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    write_to:             %assetic.read_from%
    java:                 /usr/bin/java
    node:                 /usr/bin/node
    node_paths:           []
    ruby:                 /usr/bin/ruby
    sass:                 /usr/bin/sass
    variables:
        # Prototype
        name:                 []
    bundles:
        # Defaults:
        - FrameworkBundle
        - SecurityBundle
        - TwigBundle
        - MonologBundle
        - SwiftmailerBundle
        - AsseticBundle
        - DoctrineBundle
        - SensioFrameworkExtraBundle
        - FOSUserBundle
        - JMSSerializerBundle
        - YuccaPrerenderBundle
        - WebProfilerBundle
        - SensioDistributionBundle
        - SensioGeneratorBundle
    assets:
        # Prototype
        name:
            inputs:               []
            filters:              []
            options:

                # Prototype
                name:                 []
    filters:
        # Prototype
        name:                 []
    twig:
        functions:

            # Prototype
            name:                 []
```

So, my config looks like :

```yaml
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:
      - PlastoriaGiftoFrontBundle
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    node: "/usr/bin/nodejs"
    node_paths: [ "/home/webadmin/websites/gifto/node_modules" ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less: ~
        closure:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar
```

To test that it works, I do open the Symfony Console and issue `cache:clear`
Then I go to the cache dir (app/cache) and do `rm -rf *`.
After I come back in Symfony console and launch these two commands:

```yaml
assets:install
assetic:dump
```

And I am greeted with the following message :

> Dumping all dev assets. Debug mode is on. 13:51:22 [file+]
>   /home/webadmin/websites/gifto/app/../web/css/ac28136.css 
>   [Assetic\Exception\FilterException]  An error occurred while running: 
>   '/usr/bin/nodejs' '/tmp/assetic_lessjHtxDR'  Error Output: 
>   module.js:340
>        throw err;
>              ^  Error: Cannot find module 'less'
>        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)  ... (truncated)

The configuration for the node binary is taken into account :  `An error occurred while running: '/usr/bin/nodejs'`

By default, the value is `/usr/bin/nodejs`.

I can't figure out what's wrong. Did install "less" node module in the application using *npm* and when issuing `npm ls`, I can see it is properly installed.

I also launched *nodejs* in the application directory and did a `require('less')` and it worked without error.

What is the right way of configuring assetic with nodejs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found,

I entered in the server as *root* (Yes, I know, bad practice) then I `su webadmin`!

The trick is to really login as *webadmin* or `su webadmin -l`.

I tested and it was the issue.

Answer (score 3):

For mac users this is

```
node: "/usr/local/bin/node"
node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```yaml
assetic:
   node_paths:           [/usr/lib/node_modules/]
```

in your config.yml file.

`/usr/lib/node_modules/` works for Ubuntu.

Comment: As you may have noticed, I found the root cause of it.

Comment: Did you manage to pass less filter some options? (I'm particularly interested in cmd line --strict-imports).

Comment: where is this for centos installs instead of ubunto?

Answer (score 1):

I was using Centos with a cPanel installation.  I made the mistake of not realizing when you run npm install less that it would be in the directory I called that from, which in my case was my project root directory.

Whatever directory you were in when you installed less the node_modules folder should be there.  This is the wrong location for it however.

Assuming you are in the same directory you ran the install from... Run this command to move it to the correct location

```
mv node_modules /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Then you need to add a line to your config.yml

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        uglifyjs2:
            # the path to the uglifyjs executable
            bin: /usr/bin/uglifyjs
        uglifycss:
            bin: /usr/bin/uglifycss
        less: 
            node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/]
            bin: /usr/bin/less
```

In my case I'm using a lot of other filters, but the key here is the `node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/]`, make sure you have that. Notice that is now set to a location that the script can access globally.

Now it will work.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: `node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/]` was the bit I was missing, cheers. I couldn't see this in the docs.